# Would a charged particle moving through a carbon nanotube experience no or negligible bremsstrahlung?

Tags: fusion, graphene, nanoscience, particle-accelerators

The context here is for [beam-target fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion#Beam-beam_or_beam-target_fusion). The supposition is that it *would* actually possible to achieve breakeven with an accelerator-based system and cold targets based solely on a modest electrical acceleration (~10 keV) and the D-D fusion cross section (see [here](http://www.lehigh.edu/~eus204/Teaching/ME362/lectures/Mid1_Review.pdf), page ~70 and surrounding discussion). What kills the efficiency of this system is the bremsstrahlung losses between the particles and the "cold" (i.e. <<1 million K) electrons of the target.

However, if one derives the Bethe-Block formulation for stopping power, there is a symmetric cancellation of the *parallel* force between the moving charge and the stationary electrons. The entire interaction is mediated through *perpendicular* force between the charged particle and the cold electron. (can't cite more than 2 links, but you can Google to find what I'm talking about).

So the question is, could these forces be suppressed to zero or near-zero for particles travelling down the axis of a 2D electron system like, say, a carbon nanotube? Such a system would have very little polarizability out-of-plane (perpendicular to the particle's velocity vector).

More broadly, is there research on how to manipulate bremsstrahlung interactions based on electron dynamics in confined (i.e. nanotube/nanowire/2D sheet) electronic systems?

Comment: My unverified thought: D-D reactions will overwhelmingly not occur due to Coulomb repulsion, even in a nanotube (it does not change the problem). The issue is not only the target "spectator" atoms causing losses, but the bremsstrahlung between "fuel" atoms.

Comment: At 10keV the D-D cross section is well below $10^{-4}$ barns. By 100keV it is well over 1 barn. You really don't want to be down at 10keV. But, what is the point of the nanotube? Accelerate D in to a gas of deuterium...